# Are there bigtable uses that are anti-patterns? Especially, will doing many writes of the same data (same key) be an issue?

Tags: cassandra, bigtable

I've been using Cassandra and have run into various problems with Tombstones¹. These would cause detrimental issues when I would later run a query. For example, if I overwrite the same few rows over and over again, even though I still have 5 **valid** rows in my database, it can take minutes to read them because the Cassandra system would have to read over all the Tombstones to finally reach the useful data.

What I'm wondering is whether Google Bigtable has a similar anti-pattern?

In my situation, I will be using the Bigtable to do many writes, up to 10,000 a minute, and once an hour, another app reads the data to update its caches to the latest. Many of the writes are actually updates to existing rows (same key).

¹ *Tombstones: what's left behind when deleting or updating a row in a Cassandra database. These get removed from the database when a compression of the table occurs, assuming it is given time to run said compression.*

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/cloud-bigtable-for-cassandra-users#data_updates)?

Comment: @mustaccio Unfortunately, I can't see anything about anti-patterns and whether such _pounding_ is fine with bigtables. Very interesting readings, though. I've also looked into the garbage collection information which explains TTL and max. number of versions. The compression mechanism sounds very similar for both implementations so in that sense it sounds like bigtables could have the same issue as Cassandra. On the other hand, they use Colossus to save the data and they may be able to do it on time no matter what.